# Why does a GET request for an mp4 file in Safari fail?

Tags: iis, safari, mime-types, mp4, jwplayer

I'm trying to load an mp4 file using the Javascript JWPlayer API, but when I do this in Safari the GET request to retrieve the video file fails. Looking at the GET request generated I think I can see why: the MIME type listed for the request is "undefined" whereas the type should be "video/mp4".

After quite a bit of research I can't seem to find/comprehend any way to resolve this issue.

I already have the mp4 file extension associated with the video/mp4 MIME type on my server. I'm using IIS.

This problem does not occur when I try to load the video in Chrome or IE. It's only an issue with Safari.

This was not an issue before today. If you have any suggestions I would be happy to try them out. I'm at the point where I'm grasping at straws!

Comment: A link to your page might help. Without that, no one else can do any debugging at all.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are trying to run this?